# Special Rounding

Tags: sql, rounding, floor, ceil

How can I round price value to the desired results, when use round it gives me different results and also ceiling is different !

```
select ceiling(price)

 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | test following numbers as inputted price value | Is my desired Output |
 |             INPUT                              |   OUTPUT             |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  879999.51357924604783137                      |  880000              |
 |  879999.50720242608036391                      |  880000              |
 |  879999.47819604919865821                      |  880000              |
 |  879999.49455676516329704                      |  880000              |
 |  880000.5                                      |  880000              |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What rules are you trying to apply to this rounding? A `CEILING` operation rounds up in all cases.  A `ROUND` operation will round up for any fraction greater than or equal to .5. The desired output doesn't fit either of those criteria. Are you trying to round in the 10's place instead of the 1's?

Comment: you should give more details about your desired results.

Comment: divide with 10000, round, multiply 10000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ceiling** returns the integer equal to or higher than the value

```
SELECT ceiling(879999.51357924604783137)
```

**round(X,N)** rounds to N digits:

N > 0: round to N digits to the right of the decimal point.

N = 0: round to the nearest integer.

**N < 0**: **round to N digits to the left of the decimal point**.

then

```
 select cast(round(879999.51357924604783137,-1) as decimal(18,0))
 select cast(round( 880000.5,-1) as decimal(18,0))
```

[image]

Comment: @MahdiIBM round(X,N) rounds to N digits:

N > 0: round to N digits to the right of the decimal point.

N = 0: round to the nearest integer.

N < 0: round to N digits to the left of the decimal point.  please use this :  select cast(round( 880000.5,-1) as decimal(18,0))